# how to convert the text to json in angular and how to loop the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

Am new to Angularjs, any one can help me about this
infact  my array is like this

```
array = [{"loc_name":"pronto network office","address":"3rd floor, kalyani motors","ap":[]}],
```

but when i use at dynamically its converted like this

```
[" {\"loc_name\":\"pronto="" network="" office\",\"address\":\"3rd="" floor,="" kalyani="" motors\",\"ap\":[]}"]
```

finally  i want like this

```
<ul ng-repeat="loc in [" {\"loc_name\":\"pronto=" " network=" " office\",\"address\":\"3rd=" " floor,=" " kalyani=" " motors\",\"ap\":[]} "]"="">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="list-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="location-info">
            <h4 class="location-name">{{ loc.loc_name }}</h4>
            <p class="location-address">{{ loc.address }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="loc.aps != '' ">
        <ul ng-repeat="ap in loc.aps">
            <li class="clearfix">
                <div class="list-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="location-info">
                    <h4 class="location-name">{{ ap.mac_id }}</h4>
                    <p class="location-address"></p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response should not contain `"` at starting of object inside array right after `[` and just before `]` need to remove `"` like  it should be like `[{\"loc_name\":\"pronto="" network="" office\",\"address\":\"3rd="" floor,="" kalyani="" motors\",\"ap\":[]}]`

Then place it in your scope variable `$scope.locations = [{\"loc_name\":\"pronto="" network="" office\",\"address\":\"3rd="" floor,="" kalyani="" motors\",\"ap\":[]}]` & refer that scope variable on html then you need to worry about to convert it to double quote`"` to '`' single quote.

```
<ul ng-repeat="loc in locations">
  ...
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use single quotes instead of `"`:

```
<ul ng-repeat="loc in [{loc_name: 'pronto network office', address: '3rd floor, kalyani motors', ap: []}]">
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

You can also omit quotes around keys: string inside `ngRepeat` doesn't have to comply string JSON notation with quoted keys. Of course you can still use `'` for keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want your array inside your html? Otherwise to make it simple and recommended way of doing is to move it to your controller in the JS. I have created a sample in http://jsbin.com/tayege/2/edit?html,js,output for you

Comment: I suggested the same in my answer